# contribute page for membership admin use only

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, joomla

I am using Civicrm 4.6 with Joomla! 2.5
I am looking to port our existing manual membership to civicrm. I have set up the membership categories and creating new memberships through the civicrm backend seems to work fine.

The charity will have two or three people who will administer memberships. I have created a Joomla user group and ACL for membership admin and added these users to the group. I have created a menu item which this ACL can access which is linked to a civicrm contribute page for individual membership renewal.

The issue that i have is that when one of the membership admin users logs into Joomla!, follows the link to the contribute page they appear to only be able to add a membership to their own contact record and not to be able to select the contact for which they will administer the membership add.

Any ideas on which i should look at to enable these administrators to process membership on any contact (or to add a new contact to process a membership).

I don't want the membership administrators to have access to the full civicrm, just to give them what they need to carry out their role.

Many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 2):

If you set your link to the contribution page so that it has the following at the end of the url - &cid=0 - then you should see the page load with no contact linked to it. And if you set the cid to an existing contact id, then people with permission would see the form loaded with that contacts data in place. EG

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&cid=0 should load with no contact

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&cid=203 should load with contact 203

Does that help you when combined with the right permissions?

Comment: In Drupal, which I realise you are not, you could also generate a view/search with links to go to these urls directly. Mentioning only in case it is useful to others or offers a hint for how else to approach this.

Comment: thanks for replying. I didn't notice that when i follow the Joomla! menu link it gives an option "want to do this for a different person". When i follow this link i can see in the URL that the cid=0 just like in your example above :). This however takes me to a page which will only allow me to create a new membership for an existing member i.e. i cannot create a new contact for which to process their first membership.  I have set up both new and renewals on the contributions page being used. maybe there is another step that i am missing.

Comment: my memory is that cid=0 allows you to fill in the form for a brand new contact, or you can click on the word 'here' and search the db for existing contacts. is that not what you are seeing?